# Transferring using ADO 5 worksheets into 5 tables

Tags: ms-access, excel, ado, vba

I have been struggling to transfer data from multiple excel worksheets into multiple access tables. So how this goes is this way. I have 5 worksheets and each of this worksheet is to be transferred from Excel into a specific Access table. How do I do this using VBA?

I cant seem to put the file in so I hope you guys understand!
Thanks in advance for helping me!!

Comment: What version of Office are you using?

Comment: Hi Excel Developers! My Office is 2010 at work but at home only Access is 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ADO. First, set a reference to the ADO library in the VBE: Tools, References. Look for Microsoft ActiveX Date Objects Library 6.1 (or 6.0) and tick the box next to it.

Then you can use the code below to post data from a sheet to a table in the Access database (use this in a loop if you want to do multiple sheets):

```
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim arr() As Variant

'Load the data from a sheet into an array
arr = Sheets(1).Range("A2:B10").Value

'Connect to Access database
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

With cn
    .ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Documents\Database1.accdb"
    .Open
End With

'Post data to table
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

With rs
    .Source = "Table1"
    .ActiveConnection = cn
    .CursorType = adOpenStatic
    .CursorLocation = adUseServer
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
    .Open

    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        .AddNew

        For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
            .Fields(j).Value = arr(i, j)    'This assumes you have an autonumber ID field. (Field indexes in recordsets are 0 based.)
        Next

        .Update
    Next

    .Close
End With

'Clean up
Set rs = Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
```

EDIT:

If you want to check if a record already exists in the table, use the recordset FILTER property. Say you have an "ID" in column 1 of your spreadsheet and an "ID" field in your database table, then do:

```
rs.Filter = "ID='" & arr(1,j) & "'"

If rs.RecordCount > 0 then
    'Record(s) already exist
...
```

Comment: Hi Excel Developers, if lets say the range that I am looking at has some values that are already inside the Access table, how do I manipulate through each worksheet for each table. I know I have to use the SELECT code but the code has a fixed value for the sheet its looking for...

Comment: I noticed the table is a fixed name, what if each table has a varying name for each varying excel spreadsheet? For example BVA worksheet for table BVA and EVA worksheet for table EVA?

Comment: Create a variable for the table/sheet name, say "tablename". Then change `.Source = "Table1"` to `.Source = tablename`.

Comment: Hi Excel Developers! Thanks so much I managed to fix it. Now I can transfer data from excel into access easily. Being the first time on this, should I post my codes out here so it can help others if they face the same problem?

Comment: I don't think you need to post your code here, but it is good practice to mark the best answer as the one that solved your question.